# Abstract Class comp error? Java

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and just trying to get the basics down. I am throwing a code with my main class objects in my abstract class and I'm not sure what to change.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m(new GraduateStudent());
        m(new Student());
        m(new Person());
        m(new Object());
    }

    public static void m(Student x) {
       System.out.println(x.toString());
    }
}

class GraduateStudent extends Student {
}

class Student extends Person {
    public String toString() {
        return "Student";
    }
}

class Person extends Object {
    public String toString() {
        return "Person";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Also you don't need to extend the `Person` class from `Object`. Keep in mind, `If a class isn't extended from any other class, By default it's extended from Object`. And as per coderz, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Simply Change

```
public static void m(Student x) {
        System.out.println(x.toString());
}
```

to

```
public static void m(Object x) {
        System.out.println(x.toString());
      }
```

Because all child classes can be casted to parent, parents can't be casted to child